# Make_flaggable - wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, arguments, sql-like, helper

I'm trying to use the gem for the like/unlike button in a tutorial section of my Rails application ( 
https://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable ) but I occurred in one error which it's driving me crazy. The error is **`wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`** and occurs when the view calls the method `toggle_like_button`.

In the tutorials helper there's a method called `toggle_like_button` that says if the current user likes or don't like the video yet. Then in the tutorials controller I've created a method def like that allows to unlike a content previously liked and vice versa.

This is the gem:

```
gem 'make_flaggable', :git => 'https://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable.git'
```

This is in the `application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false
```

This is the toggle_like_button method in tutorials helper:

```
def toggle_like_button (tutorial, user)
    if user.flagged?(user, :like)
      link_to 'Unlike', like_tutorial_path(tutorial)
    else
      link_to 'Like', like_tutorial_path(tutorial)
    end
  end
```

This is the tutorials controller:

```
def like
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.flagged?(@tutorial, :like)
       current_user.unflag(@tutorial, :like)
      msg = 'you now like'
    else
      current_user.flag(@tutorial, :like)
      msg = 'you dislike'
    end
    redirect_to tutorial_path, :notice => msg
  end
```

This is the view which calls the tutorials_helper method:

```
<% if @current_user.present? %>
    <%= toggle_like_button(@tutorial, @current_user) %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: please also post the complete error with line on which you get the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can like and dislike tutorial on the basis of flag.
Try this:

```
def toggle_like_button (tutorial, user)
    if user.flagged?(tutorial, :like)
      link_to 'Unlike', like_tutorial_path(tutorial)
    else
      link_to 'Like', like_tutorial_path(tutorial)
    end
end
```

Also see:

**usage of your gem**

```
# Returns true if the flagger flagged the flaggable, false otherwise.
user.flagged?(article, :flag_name)

# Returns true if the flagger flagged the flaggable, false otherwise.
user.flagged?(article)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now! I used the second solution that you wrote!

Comment: I have also same error @G.B , but it is not working in my code. Can you check it,please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34107744/argumenterror-in-staticpageshome-after-adding-toggle-support-button