# ArgumentError in StaticPages#home after adding toggle_support_button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ve already added flaggings to micropost with make_flaggable gem. Everything work in my app until adding microposts_helper.rb

**Error-wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) in views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb**

```
 def toggle_support_button(micropost,user)
    ***if user.flagged?(micropost, :support)***
    # We already like this
    link_to "Not Support", support_micropost_path(micropost)
 else
```

**_micropost.html.erb**

```
   <% if current_user.present? %>
     <%= toggle_support_button(micropost,current_user) %>
   <%end%>
```

**microposts_helper.rb**

```
module MicropostsHelper

   def toggle_support_button(micropost,user)
      if user.flagged?(micropost, :support)
       # We already like this
      link_to "Not Support", support_micropost_path(micropost)
   else
       # We don't like this yet
       link_to "Support", support_micropost_path(micropost)
   end
 end
end
```

**microposts_controller.rb**

```
 def support
   @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])

   if current_user.flagged?(micropost, :support)
    # We already like this
    @current_user.unflag(@micropost, :support)

   else
     # We don't like this yet
    @current_user.flag(@micropost, :support)
   end
    redirect_to request.referrer

 end
```

Comment: If you post your error stack it will be easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: @froderik, Thanks .. I've already edited it

Comment: The error means that the `flagged?` method only accepts one argument but your are passing in two.

Comment: @froderik, Yes, I've got it. But a micropost can have 2 flags. One is 'support', the other one is 'Favorite'. I just want that the user click the button for support; the support button must change. When I write as " if user.flagged?(micropost) ", the button also changed when I add flag as favorite.

Comment: Can you put your code of `flagged?` methode in `User` model?

Comment: @Yang - it is not in his/her model - it comes from the gem being used.

Comment: @Takor - this would mean that you have the wrong code loaded - old version of the gem perhaps?

Comment: @froderik - I've installed this one. " gem 'make_flaggable', :git => 'git://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now I have a clear idea about what is going on. You are using the gem **make_flaggable** directly from github. (This is in itself perhaps not a good idea. On the other hand - the one [published](https://rubygems.org/gems/make_flaggable) is at version 0.0.3 - an indicator of this being work in progress.) You have probably read the documentation that says that there indeed is a `flagged?(article, flag_name)` method. However - if you have a look in [the code](https://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable/blob/master/lib/make_flaggable/flagger.rb#L69) - you will find that it only accepts one argument. So your problem is that this inmature gem has a mismatch between its documentation and its implementation.

What to do now? You can investigate if you can get away with the one argument method. I guess it depends if you need different flags for the same user and item. Otherwise you can always fork the repo and make the needed changes. Since it is in the documentation the original author may well accept a pull request for this feature.

On a side note. It may be useful to know that the source code of all the gems you download are readily available on your hard drive. Just run `gem which make_flaggable` to find it.

Comment: Thank you so much @froderik.. I'll add only one flag,because everything become complicated when I tried to add 3 flags for same item. You're right. I'll find different solutions for adding properties to my app.